# aws-sdk v3 lambda region missing even after providing region

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-js-v3

I'm migrating aws-sdk from v2 to v3 and I'm having trouble setting up the lambda client. I'm providing region during the instantiation of lambda client as shown in the docs but while running InvokeAsyncCommand on the client, I get "Region is missing" error.

The sandbox contains the issue reproduced

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-robinson-ljqfo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `clientConfig: {region: "region-here"}` in `fromCognitoIdentityPool` solved the issue.
I've left the code sandbox unedited for reference.

Comment: Thanks, I was really caught up with the docs and it was not at all helpful w.r.t to passing region info correctly